# Как декодировать gzip?

Tags: c#

Есть json-строка, которую возвращает bittrix api.

```
{"C":"d-88903F9C-uIVg,2|Cv,81594","G":"f8N0wWnjI7HYfemJI8e0xCbSANWfxnpNCIT4iAHhWDhZjpcgeesgN6r5uUtMrGXJhuLnOyMI52yEsxDhlxcpAJc6+oPWpOx4b7k2EWza50QZM5sNKXQHzanncDgQPzJQc7yWAg==","M":[]}
```

То что идет после **G** это по идее gzip строка. Я пытаюсь её дешифровать, но он пишет `{"Неизвестный тип блока. Поток может быть поврежден."}`

```
public static string Decode(string wireData)
        {
            try
            {
                // Step 1: Base64 decode the wire data into a gzip blob
                byte[] gzipData = Convert.FromBase64String(wireData);

                // Step 2: Decompress gzip blob into minified JSON
                using (var decompressedStream = new MemoryStream())
                using (var compressedStream = new MemoryStream(gzipData))
                using (var deflateStream = new DeflateStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                {
                    deflateStream.CopyTo(decompressedStream);
                    decompressedStream.Position = 0;

                    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(decompressedStream))
                    {
                        return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return "";
            }

        }
```

Comment: [GZipStream](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.gzipstream?view=netframework-4.7.2). А вообще, похоже что там `Base64`, а потом `GZip`.

Comment: @LLENN ну так мой код это и делает

Comment: @Radzhab потому что это ни gzip, ни deflate, читайте доки